# Looping through cells but only changing details in certain ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I've got an excel sheet that has made labels but I need a macro to change parts of said labels, please see current code below. I understand why this doesn't work as it is looking at the columns `SZ` rather than column `S` row `z`(variable `int`). Just wondered if anybody had a fix.

```
Sub CleanupTest()
'
' CleanupTest Macro

Dim No_Of_Rows As Integer

    No_Of_Rows = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    x = No_Of_Rows
    MsgBox No_Of_Rows
    Z = 9
    y = 7
    For i = 1 To (x / 20)
        Range("Hz:Jz").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NA"
        Range("Uz:Yz").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "798742"
        Range("AGz:AIz").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NA"
        Range("ATz:AXz").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "798742"
        Range("Sy:Yy").Select
        Range("Sy:Yy").Cut Destination:=Range("S6:Y6")
        Range("ARy:AXy").Select
        Range("ARy:AXy").Cut Destination:=Range("AR6:AX6")
        Range("Sy:AXy").Select
        With Selection.Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        Z = Z + 20
        y = y + 20
        
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("H" & z & ":J" & z").Select`  also this would be better `Range("H" & z & ":J" & z").value="NA"`

Comment: Little correction to the above suggestion to remove last " in the parenthesis ..  `Range("H" & z & ":J" & z) = "NA"` and similarly for variable y

Answer (score 1):

I hope the "final code" in your answer is not your final code: there is no need to select first and do something with the `ActiveCell` afterwards, this piece is code is doing exactly the same without the obsolete selecting and "`ActiveCell`ing":

```
Range("H" & Z & ":J" & Z).FormulaR1C1 = "NA"
Range("AG" & Z & ":AI" & Z).FormulaR1C1 = "NA"
Range("AT" & Z & ":AX" & Z).FormulaR1C1 = "798742"
Range("U" & Z & ":U" & Z).FormulaR1C1 = "798742"
Z = Z + 21
Range("H" & Z & ":J" & Z).FormulaR1C1 = "NA"
Range("AG" & Z & ":AI" & Z).FormulaR1C1 = "NA"
Range("AT" & Z & ":AX" & Z).FormulaR1C1 = "798742"
Range("U" & Z & ":U" & Z).FormulaR1C1 = "798742"
```

Comment: Also, not sure of your situation, but may be worth checking the dividing too, as if x=47 for example, could be an error.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, couldn't have done it without ya!

Please see final code below:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Dim No_Of_Rows As Integer

    No_Of_Rows = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

    MsgBox No_Of_Rows
    x = No_Of_Rows
    Z = 9
    y = 9
    For i = 1 To (x / 46) + 1
        Range("H" & Z & ":J" & Z).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NA"
        Range("AG" & Z & ":AI" & Z).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NA"
        Range("AT" & Z & ":AX" & Z).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "798742"
        Range("U" & Z & ":U" & Z).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "798742"
        Z = Z + 21
        Range("H" & Z & ":J" & Z).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NA"
        Range("AG" & Z & ":AI" & Z).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NA"
        Range("AT" & Z & ":AX" & Z).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "798742"
        Range("U" & Z & ":U" & Z).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "798742"
        Z = Z + 25
    Next i
End Sub
```